# Regarding the properties files in java

Tags: java

I am using `DBPropperties.properties` for configuring my Database properties. Later i changed that to `DBPropperties.properties_BKP` and create another `DBPropperties.properties` file.

But in my logs still the configuration things i mentioned in the `DBPropperties.properties_BKP`file is coming along with `DBPropperties.properties` file?

Am not getting why it is picking the values from the `*.properties_BKP` files. Am running my application in Tomcat 6.1, java version 5. Theni remove the `DBPropperties.properties_BKP` from `Tomcat.6.1/webapps/myapplication/WEB-INF/classes/` its not coming and working fine. What is the reason for picking the values from a file ends with an extension other than properties?

Comment: Look at your Tomcat/work/Catalina/<localhost>/<WebApp> folder, probably it's a redeploy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you properly close the file after reading the properties. Otherwise, the web server might be unable to delete the file when you redeploy.

Next, check the `Tomcat/work/Catalina/<localhost>/<WebApp>` folder for any old copies. If you have problems, stop Tomcat, delete the folder for your webapp and redeploy. If that solves the problem, check your code for file handle leaks.

Comment: thank you sir. Initially i dont delete my tmp and work folder.But second time i deleted both folders and run my application and it is working fine. Thanks for the answer